# How to make header full width of website?

Tags: html, css

I need to know how to make the header image cover the full width of the website:

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div id="header" align="center">
        <img name="Antique Picture" src="C:\website\Header.jpg" alt="logo">
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {          
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the what I am trying to do:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 2):

first don't use `align="center"` then use `width:100%` in `img`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img name="Antique Picture" src="//placehold.it/1500x900" alt="logo" />
</header>
```

**UPDATE** based on your updated question

here is how to do it

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
header {
  background: red
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img name="Antique Picture" src="//placehold.it/1500x900" alt="logo" />
</header>
```

Comment: I have done this https://gyazo.com/b2ce24d0d4125316a45a0c369f6e65bf what would I have to do to make the image better quality?

Comment: Make it in a higher resolution

Comment: your image is low resolution

Comment: @willtcrook see updated answer based on your updated question

Answer (score 0):

```
<img name="Antique Picture" src="C:\website\Header.jpg" alt="logo" width="100%">
```

In the above image tag, you need to add width as 100% will.

Comment: Ok thankyou , is there anyway to make the img better quality as it is quite low now https://gyazo.com/b2ce24d0d4125316a45a0c369f6e65bf?